# Contagem de array em VUE com condicional

Tags: javascript

estou precisando descobrir quantos registros da array abaixo tem o campo active como true, como posso fazer?

```
[ { "name": "Quero Vender", "active": false }, 
{ "name": "Quero Comprar","active": false } ]
```

Comment: Você só quer a contagem ou quer saber quais tem `active === true` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TL;DR

Você pode usar o método [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) para retornar uma soma dos itens, somando 1 quando `active` é `true` e `0` caso contrário.

```
dados.reduce((acc, {active}) => acc + !!active, 0)
```

---

### Explicação

O método [`Array.reduce(callback, initialValue)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) itera sobre um array e salva em uma "variável" o resultado de cada iteração. Esta variável é chamada **acumulador** e seu valor inicial é definido no segundo parâmetro do método. O acumulador é bastante confundido como "item anterior" onde usam o reduce desta maneira:

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce((anterior, atual) => anterior + atual)
```

No último passo do código acima, `anterior` será igual a `3` e `atual` também será `3`, pois o primeiro é a soma de `1 + 2` que foi o valor acumulado e o segundo é o 3º item do array que contém o valor `3`.

É um erro comum e por isso eu sempre aconselho a nomear como **acc** ou qualquer coisa que lembre que é um acumulador para evitar confusões.

E é bom lembrar que se o valor de acumulador não for definido será utilizado o primeiro valor do array e lançará um erro se o array for vazio (afinal, não existe primeiro elemento em um array vazio). Alguns exemplos de uso:

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce((acc, num) => acc + num)     // 6
[1, 2, 3].reduce((acc, num) => acc + num, 0)  // 6
[1, 2, 3].reduce((acc, num) => acc + num, 10) // 16
[1, 2, 3].reduce((acc, num) => acc + num, "") // "123"
```

---

Ao receber o item do array estou usando `(acc, {active}) => ...` que é uma funcionalidade do [ECMAScript 2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-assignment) chamada [*Destructuring assignment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) que permite que eu pegue apenas as partes que preciso de um objeto ou array.

Neste caso, estou pegando apenas o valor da propriedade `active` do objeto, pois é a única informação que preciso dele. Ex.:

```
let obj = {nome: "Teste", active: true}
let {active} = obj
console.log(active)  // true
```

---

E por último me aproveito do fato de que converter valores booleanos para [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) geram valores `1` e `0` para `true` e `false`, respectivamente.

```
console.log(Number(true))  // 1
console.log(Number(false)) // 0
```

Também utilizo o operador `!` para converter o valor para um booleano.

```
console.log(!!1)  // true
console.log(!!0)  // false
```

---

Sabendo das informações anteriores fica mais fácil entender que o código cria um acumulador com valor `0` e soma `1` quando `active === true`, chegando ao resultado que é um contador de itens ativos.

---

Código funcionando:

```js
let dados = [
  {name: "Quero Vender", active: false},
  {name: "Quero Comprar", active: false}
]

let count = dados.reduce((acc, {active}) => acc + !!active, 0)

console.log(count)  // 0

// Adiciona alguns items ativos
dados.push({name: "Teste", active: true})
dados.push({name: "Teste 2", active: true})

count = dados.reduce((acc, {active}) => acc + !!active, 0)

console.log(count)  // 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer algo do tipo

```js
let meuArray = [
  { "name": "Quero Vender", "active": false },
  { "name": "Quero Comprar","active": false },
  { "name": "Quero Tudo","active": true },
  { "name": "Quero Nada","active": true }
]

let contaActive = (array) => {
  let numeroDeActive = 0
  
  array.forEach(element => {
    if (element.active === true) numeroDeActive++
  })

  return numeroDeActive
} 

console.log(contaActive(meuArray))
```

Como você está usando `VueJS`, ao invés de declarar uma função, você pode usar um **method** ou **computed**, ai vai depender da sua necessidade.