# Selecionar uma informação que se repete muitas vezes

Tags: javascript, angular

Gostaria de saber se existe algum meio de selecionar uma informação que se repete muitas vezes. Exemplo:
Tenho um array de objeto:

`array = [{fruta: maçã}, {fruta: maçã}, {fruta: banana}]`

Notem que a fruta maçã se repete 2 vezes e a banana apenas 1.

Precisava que uma variável recebesse a 'Maçã' pois ela é a que mais aparece.

Estou fazendo assim:
`this.variavel = array[0].fruta` porém dessa forma eu só estou pegando a primeira e não a que mais aparece.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um objeto que com a contagem de cada fruta usando [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) e passando um objeto como acumulador. Aí a cada passo você incrementa a chave que contem a fruta encontrada dentro do reduce.

Depois que você tiver o objeto com as contagens você pode utilizar o [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) novamente para retornar apenas o maior da entradas do objetos([Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)).

```js
let frutas = [
  {fruta: "maçã"}, 
  {fruta: "maçã"}, 
  {fruta: "banana"},
  {fruta: "melancia"},
  {fruta: "maçã"}, 
  {fruta: "banana"}
];

// counter carrega um objeto no formato {nome_fruta: num_ocorrencias}
let counter = frutas.reduce((acc, {fruta}) => {
  acc[fruta] = (acc[fruta] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(counter)

// recebe nas variáveis o nome da fruta com mais ocorrências, com o número de ocorrências
 let [nome_fruta, num_ocorrencias] = Object.entries(counter).reduce((acc, entry) => entry[1] > acc[1] ? entry : acc);

console.log(`A fruta "${nome_fruta}" apareceu ${num_ocorrencias} vezes na listagem de frutas.`);
```

---

[Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/350023/6333) explico um pouco melhor sobre o funcionamento do [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) do parâmetro acumulador.